# How to notify the user of Azure blob trigger function success/ failure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, csv, upload, blob

I have the following:

1) ASP.NET web app deployed to Azure. Allows user to select a CSV file to upload.

2) BLOB storage in Azure. The above web app copies the csv file to a blob.

3) Blob trigger function. This processes the CSV file, inserting the contents into an Azure SQL Server table.

The problem is that, although the user gets notified of a successful upload to the blob, the user has no way of knowing whether the csv file was successfully processed by the blob trigger. E.g. there could be some error in the csv file contents that needs to be fed back to the user, or maybe the blob trigger function failed to run.

How is it possible to notify the web app user of success/ failure of the blob trigger function to insert the data into the database table? It seems to me that, although a neat solution, it's fundamentally flawed in this respect as the data loading is a decoupled two-step process, rather than all being done in one go. Unless there's some way of notifying the user?

Alternatively, is there a better architectural solution? E.g. can the web app simply insert directly into the Azure SQL Server database? (However, a requirement is to store the original csv files somewhere, for future reference - where could these be stored?)

Comment: This is, of course, inherent to using asynchronous processing. Have a look at using [Azure SignalR service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/) to notify the user.

Comment: As said before this is the common behaviour of async. You could however, as you say, create the blob and after the blob is created just put it on an azure database all in one step without relying on triggers. What exactly is making that approach hard?

Comment: For the alternative, you can store it in blob, then use websites read data to azure sql. Is it acceptable?